# Tails Graphics/driver help

Tags: tails, help

New to Tails and would appreciate some assistance.

I currently have a Geforce GTX 970 with a 1920 X 1080 monitor (primary) connected via DVI-D and a old 1024 X 768 VGA connected using a DVI-I adapter. Nvidia has kindly made analogue devices the primary output device resulting in me needing to use the older monitor to enter the bios and for tails. I can handle it for the bios as I can use my primary monitor fine in windows. I would however prefer to use the 1920X1080 monitor in Tails and I can only achieve that by disconnecting the vga monitor which is rather annoying.

Could someone talk me through how to install a driver or tweak so I can use my primary monitor or point me in the right direction please?

Comment: what does the display-settings menu show?

Comment: I do not have an answer but I have the same question - I am showing up with unknown monitor and have tried various xrandr and tweaks to get my GTX970 card to work